# $H$ is a normal subgroup (containing an element of infinite order) of the permutation group over positive integers , then is $H$ the whole group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, infinite-groups

Let $S(\mathbb N)$ be the set of all bijections on $\mathbb N$ ( the set of positive integers ) endowed with the natural group structure of function composition . If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $S(\mathbb N)$ such that $H$ contains an element of infinite order then is it true that $H=S(\mathbb N)$ ?

Comment: @Crostul : No progress literally ... I am also at a loss how does the normal subgroups look like here ...

Comment: The answer is yes. The only nontrivial proper normal subgroups are the groups of all permutations with finite support, and all even permutations with finite support, neither of which has elements of infinite order.

Comment: This was proposed in the Review list of Close votes. I dutifully clicked the option Close, for an obvious lack of context. Surprise! "This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. There are no major problems with this question. You should click Leave Open, or make minor corrections via Edit. Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above." Needless to say, I am not worrying, but I dare to disagree with this piece of lunatic nonsense. No offense...